# NetSuite - Saved Search formula for calculating percentage from summary Total

Tags: saved-searches

I would like to create a Saved Search in NetSuite that returns the percentage of Quotation in a specific month. I have achieved month wise count of quotation and in summary total is also showing as a year, I want to calculate monthly percentage based yearly total in another column. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XathU.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw3ea.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the only way to do this is Client side.

```
if (!window.hereFirst) {
    window.hereFirst = true;
    window.addEventListener(`load`, (e) => {
        let rcs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`[row-count]`));
        let tc = rcs.reduce((t, r) => t + Number(r.getAttribute(`row-count`)), 0);
        rcs.forEach(r => {
            let rp = r.parentElement;
            rp.textContent = ((Number(r.getAttribute(`row-count`)) / tc) * 100)
                .toFixed(1) + `%`;
            rp.classList.add(`listtextrt`);
        });
    });
}
```

this goes into an html image onload event.
[image: NetSuite Column Definitions]
and produces
[image: NetSuite Client Side Results]

Minimum of Formula (Text):

```
'<img style="display: none;" row-count="'||COUNT(DISTINCT {number})||'" src="/core/media/media.nl?id=#&c=#&h=..." onload="if (!window.hereFirst) { window.hereFirst = true; window.addEventListener(`load`,(e) => { let rcs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(`[row-count]`)); let tc = rcs.reduce((t,r) => t+Number(r.getAttribute(`row-count`)),0); rcs.forEach(r => { let rp = r.parentElement; rp.textContent = ((Number(r.getAttribute(`row-count`))/tc)*100).toFixed(1)+`%`; rp.classList.add(`listtextrt`); }); }); }">'
```

I use my company's logo for the image since the browser is already loading and caching it.

Comment: Thanks will check this!